# What does 狗尾巴草 mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following quote is from the short story 1934年的逃亡 by Su Tong.

> 陈宝年心中长出一棵灰暗的狗尾巴草，他在祖宗像前跪拜天地的时候，不时蜷起尖锐的五指，狠掐女人伸给他的手。

What does it mean to grow a [Setaria_viridis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setaria_viridis) in one's heart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

狗尾巴草 is a kind of weed against which peasants need to fight all the time, and it is famous for its strong vitality. So peasants and poets see 狗尾巴草 as a tough enemy. For a long time, 狗尾巴草 is called 莠 and had appeared in ancient poems and articles. Of course, its image is bad and negative.

In the paragraph you mentioned, 灰暗 plus 狗尾巴草 together imply evil thoughts.

Comment: Yes, these weeds are like politicians; the more you hate them, the faster they grow.

Answer (score 2):

狗尾巴草 `Setaria viridis` ，古稱「莠」，令人想到「良莠不齊」

Therefore, 在人們心中印象便是不好

Answer (score 1):

The hidden meanings of 狗尾草 are as follow:

"狗尾草很普通，不被人注意，也不被重视，只是一棵默默无闻的野草，但是它的生命力十分顽强，它的寓意是**坚忍、暗恋，不被人了解的爱、艰难的爱**，狗尾巴草寓意着喜欢一个人却不敢表白，它还象征着坚忍的品格，不为环境所屈服，不可轻言放弃。在生活中我们也应该学习狗尾巴草的品格和精神，**不言弃、坚强、坚忍**"

If you read through the story, you shall be able to pick one implication that fits the best.

https://news.huamu.com/huahuibaike/19746.html

Answer (score 1):

> 心中长出一棵灰暗的狗尾巴草

We can take the whole phrase to mean ***a sin growing from the bottom of his heart***.

灰暗的狗尾巴草 just gives us a bad feeling/impression about his mind and here is metaphorically representing ***a (dark)sin***.